# symlink(): Protocol error in Vagrant 2.0

Tags: laravel, vagrant, homestead

I am new to Homestead and Laravel, recently I have installed Vagrant 2.0.0 in my Windows 10 PC. I have successfully installed Laravel 5.5 however there is an error of [ErrorException]  symlink(): Protocol error. I have tried to solve this using

[Laravel 5.3 storage:link -> symlink(): Protocol error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39496598/laravel-5-3-storagelink-symlink-protocol-error)
https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/servers/creating-symbolic-link-on-homestead

But still, the solutions mentioned there seems to be not solving the issue. I can't either run Git Bash & CMD in admin mode, as it gives error while running vagrant up command.

Can anyone please give a solution for this?

Thanks in Advance
Barun

Comment: For me, running as administrator was not enough, and I still got "Protocol error" when trying to create symlinks. Here was what worked: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60741351/470749

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem

Create these folders under storage/framework:

- sessions
- views
- cache

then run terminal in administrator

- Vagrant up
- php artisan cache:clear
- php artisan config:clear
- php artisan view:clear
- php artisan storage:link

refresh the page without cache.

Answer (score 0):

I solved mine by running bash as an Admin.

**Things to notice:**
If you are using a virtual box and you run bash as an Admin, this will expect that the OS/BOX is saved in the Admin state of your virtual box as well. If not, once you vagrant up, it will redownload the OS/BOX again because it is going to save now in the Admin environments. Sorry for bad English. Hope you get what I mean...

Answer (score 0):

This may help, if you have previously renamed a folder in the virtual machine there may be an old VBoxInternal2/SharedFoldersEnableSymlinksCreate entry.  If a bad entry exists then you will receive the protocol error.  To remove the bad entries:

- VBoxManage getextradata {name of virtual machine}
- Review the list of VBoxInternal2/SharedFoldersEnableSymlinksCreate entries and for each one that is no longer valid:

  - VBoxManage setextradata {name of virtual machine} VBoxInternal2/SharedFoldersEnableSymlinksCreate/{bad entry}

Running this without a value at the end will remove the entry.  You can confirm this by running the getextradata command once more.

Then reload your vagrant box.  This resolved this issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

You must do the below steps:

1. you have sart git-bash as administrator
2. then go to the Homstead folder mostly->
   **cd: c:/users/username/homestead**
3. then type->
   **vagrant ssh** Homestead will open
4. now you navigate to your app mein folder in example:
   **cd: f:/homestead-projects      /example-app**
5. now you have to run the artisan comands:

   - php artisan cache:clear
   - php artisan config:clear
   - php artisan view:clear
   - php artisan storage:link

The Storage folder will be created at `APP->public->storage` here you see now folder created by uploading files