# Laravel 8 storage link did not make effect?

Tags: laravel

I have tried everything already and the storage:link is not working at all.

even removing the file and running `php artisan storage:link` it won't simply work.

I am getting the following error:

```
rename(/home/vagrant/code/Project/storage/app/tmp/files/SfwvkNHaA2VKlUX2/1200px-Laravel.svg.png,/home/vagrant/code/Project/public/files/6053cf08890df-1616105224_file.png): No such file or directory
```

Meaning that

`/home/vagrant/code/Project/storage/app/tmp/files/SfwvkNHaA2VKlUX2/1200px-Laravel.svg.png` cannot be found.

I have browsed in the folders and yes, the file EXISTS, but in the browser I'm getting a 404.

Any ideas on how to fix it?

I tried:

cleaning the cache

removing and linking again

manual linking

turning off the box, on again, and then provision... but still nothing.

Anyone got this issue before??

HELP!

Comment: Did you change your default public directory path?

Comment: @Droid what do you mean?

Comment: The question was wrote long ago, but it may actually help:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39496598/laravel-5-3-storagelink-symlink-protocol-error